# Issue with 0 padding using printf

Tags: java

I am formatting a variable. I'm trying to add `0` padding but I am getting ***runtime issue***.

When I remove the left justify sign "-" I can add the padding, but it's like I can't add both.

***Here is the code:***

```
  int i4 = 1000;
  System.out.printf("Format with position and spacing and left justify and locale separator and 0 padding");
  System.out.printf("%1$-,7d \n", i4); //Runs fine
  System.out.printf("%1$-,07d \n", i4); //Run time error
```

**Edit:**

On runtime I am getting: `IllegalFormatFlagsException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = '-0,'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What compile error do you get? Compiles fine for me on 1.8.0_40....

Comment: I think the problem is that it can't work out how to do the optional minus and pad the zeros.

Comment: @Adam it compiles fine for me too, but fails at run time to compile the format.

Comment: thanks, yea it's like I can't add the left justify sign " - " along with "0" ?

Comment: @HerlandCid What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: @nazar_art what I want to achieve is mixing the flags "-" and "0" when formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. The two concepts don't work together.

- If you pad with zeros using "%07d" then you'll get
  "001,000" which is 7 characters.
- Left justifying that same number 001,000 in the same format width of 7 has no effect, the answer would still be "001,000"

If you wanted to left justify the 1,000 in a larger format width you could do this in two steps...

```
System.out.printf("Result=\"%-12s\"\n", String.format("%,07d", i4));
```

Output

```
Result="001,000     "
```

Comment: Makes sence @Adam following that, it would have to be only 0 or -